# What does 触控 mean in 使用者将可轻松地以触控的方式浏览教科书内容?

Tags: mandarin, meaning, simplified-characters

I was busy reading about Apple's new textbook announcement on Engadget China, and I came across the following sentence:

> 使用者将可轻松地以触控的方式浏览教科书内容.

What is the meaning of 触控 in this sentence? (My guess is something like touch-control or touch-input?) Do these two characters form a word? How could I use this character combination in another sentence?

Comment: 触摸屏, 触控屏: touch screen, 触摸板, 触控板: touch pad. The word 触控 is commonly used in Taiwan, like that the word **user** is translated to 用户 in mainland China, but 使用者 in Taiwan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you guessed is right. 触控 is touch and control: 触 as in 触摸 (touch), and 控 as in 控制 (control).

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example sentence? Then I will accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: 触控 is a term referring to the input interface of devices like iphone/ipod touch/ipad and those android phones.  触控屏 for touchscreen, 触控板 for trackpad of macbooks...etc

Comment: Hey, Fivesheep, it's me! Glad to see you here!